# Matplotlib scatterplot subplot legends overwrite one another

Tags: loops, matplotlib, legend, scatter-plot, subplot

I have a scatterplot figure with subplots generated using a for loop. Within the figure, I am trying to create a single legend but each time a subplot and legend is rendered the legend is overwritten by the next subplot, so the figure that is generated contains a single legend pertaining only to the last subplot. I would like the legend to pertain to all subplots (i.e., it should include years 2019, 2020, 2021 and 2022). Here is my code, please let me know how I can tweak it.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches

df = pd.read_excel(path)

spp = df.SPP.unique()

fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=8, ncols=4, figsize=(14, 14))

for spp_i, ax in zip(spp, axs.flat):
    df_1 = df[df['SPP'] == spp_i]
    labels = list(df_1.Year.unique())
    x = df_1['Length_mm']
    y = df_1['Weight_g']
    levels, categories = pd.factorize(df_1['Year'])
    colors = [plt.cm.tab10(i) for i in levels]
    handles = [matplotlib.patches.Patch(color=plt.cm.tab10(i), label=c) for i, c in enumerate(categories)]
    ax.scatter(x, y, c=colors)
    plt.legend(handles=handles)

plt.savefig('Test.png', bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0.1, dpi=600)
```

Here is figure, as you can see the legend in the bottom right is for the last subplot only.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G8aRf.jpg)

Comment: Instead of `plt.legend(handles=handles)` you need `ax.legend(handles=handles)`

Comment: I tried seaborn as suggested but unfortunately each subplot has the same x and y axis which leads to species with a small data spread getting drowned out by the species with a larger spread, the matplotlib method creates a different scale for each subplot best suited to the spread of the data which is much easier to interpret.

Comment: The matplotlib option had a problem in that after using your solution above for the legend it created a legend for each subplot but the colour for each year varied among subplots, which becomes confusing. It would great if there is a way to keep the colour of each year consistent among the subplots. It is possible the reason for the inconsistency is that not all subplots have all four years.

Comment: You can add `g = sns.relplot(..., facet_kws={'sharex': False, 'sharey': False})` to give each subplot its own ranges.  You then might need `g.fig.subplots_adjust(wspace=..., hspace=...)` to change the default spacing between the subplots.  Doing all this with standard matplotlib is quite cumbersome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating this type of plots is quite cumbersome with standard matplotlib.  Seaborn automates a lot of the steps.

In this case, `sns.relplot(...)` can be used. If you don't want all the subplots to have the same x and/or y ranges, you can add `facet_kws={'sharex': False, 'sharey': False})`.

The size of the individual subplots is controlled via `height=`, while the width will be calculated as the `height` multiplied by the `aspect`. `col_wrap=` tells how many columns of subplots will be put before starting a new row.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

spp_list = ["Aeloria", "Baelun", "Caelondia", "Draeden", "Eldrida", "Faerun", "Gorandor", "Haldira", "Ilysium",
            "Jordheim", "Kaltara", "Lorlandia", "Myridia", "Nirathia", "Oakenfort"]
df = pd.DataFrame({'SPP': np.repeat(spp_list, 100),
                   'Year': np.tile(np.repeat(np.arange(2019, 2023), 25), 15),
                   'Length_mm': np.abs(np.random.randn(1500).cumsum()) + 10,
                   'Weight_g': np.abs(np.random.randn(1500).cumsum()) + 20})

g = sns.relplot(df, x='Length_mm', y='Weight_g', col='SPP', col_order=spp_list,
                hue='Year', palette='turbo',
                height=3, aspect=1.5, col_wrap=6,
                facet_kws={'sharex': False, 'sharey': False})
g.set_axis_labels(x_var='Length (mm)', y_var='Weight (g)', clear_inner=True)

g.fig.tight_layout()  # nicely fit supblots with their titles, labels and ticks
g.fig.subplots_adjust(right=0.97)  # space for the legend after fitting the subplots
plt.show()
```

[image: sns.relplot example]

Comment: This does exactly what I need, thank you.